# The word for political agenda?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for (perhaps hidden) political agenda?  For example:
‘This newspaper says it's neutral, but they actually have an obvious
agenda’.  There is ‘*agendo*’, but that's probably a false-friend.
According to [*PIV*](http://vortaro.net/#agendo):

> **agend/o**<sup>Z</sup>.  Kajero, en kiu oni notas je ĉiu tago la
>   farotajn aferojn.

I've found the word ‘*kromcelo*’, which I like, but I'm not quite sure
it's fitting, and *PIV* doesn't know the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *kolego* pointed me to the word
‘[*kaŝpenso*](http://vortaro.net/#ka%C5%9Dpenso)’, which seems to describe the
concept of hidden agenda quite well:

> **kaŝpenso**.  Penso, kiu gvidas ies agadon, sed kiun tiu kaŝas, por
>   pli certe atingi la celon.

Comment: https://glosbe.com/eo/en/kaŝpenso supports that too. It's translated as "secret thought" but also lists "hidden agenda'".

Comment: When translating a sentence using it in google translate, it occasionally is translated as "ulterior motives".

Answer (score 2):

After seeing a definition that reads: "the set of goals of an ideological group.", I'd translate it as:

```
politika celo
```

Ekzempla citaĵo el Tekstaro:

> De jarcentoj ili jam kutimis gvidi la publikan opinion kontraŭ unu aŭ
>   alia gento, laŭ la celoj politikaj de la momento.

That should be enough in most cases, but if you want to emphasize the plurality of goals you could use:

```
politika celaro
```

Both could take *kaŝita*.

Comment: Celo estas bona vorto en ĉi tiu kunteksto.Mia ekzemplo: "Tiuj personoj havas tiun publikan politikan celon, sed portas kaŝpenson kun kaŝita politika celo, ke…"

Answer (score 1):

Oficiala-sence : politika kalendaro, aŭ politika agendaro.  Ekzemple : oficiala vojaĝo al U-Han (Ĉinio) ne estas en la kalendaro de nia regestro ĉi-jare.

Okulta-sence : politika intencaro.  Tiu regestro diras sin social-demokrata, sed ŝajnegas ke ĝi nur aplikas la intencaron de la FET (Forumo Ekonomiko Tutmonda de Davos).

Answer (score 0):

En Tekstaro aperas kelkaj frazoj kun *politika agendo* en tiu senco de la angla *political agenda*. Pri la vorto *[agendo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/agend.html#agend.0o)* ReVo donas ekzemplon kun tia senco:

> la nombro de individuoj kun dekstremaj vidpunktoj kaj agendoj ŝajnas
>   kreski

Al mi ŝajnas klare ke oni povas uzi figurasence *agendo* en tiu senco. Ankaŭ *kaŝpenso* bonas, sed oni atentu ke ĝi emfazas la kaŝitecon de la celo, sed *agendo* ne nepre estas kaŝa. La vorton *kromcelo* mi komprenas kiel aldonan aŭ flankan celon, kiu povas esti kaŝa aŭ ne.